# duplicate value when write binary file

Tags: c++, file, binary

I read data from binary file, change the data and write data in binary file.

```
void VolumeData::saveBinary(std::string filePath)
{
    std::string output_file = filePath + ".bin";
    std::ofstream fs_dst( output_file.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    fs_dst.write((char *)&width, sizeof(__int32));
    fs_dst.write((char *)&height, sizeof(__int32));
    fs_dst.write((char *)&depth, sizeof(__int32));
    fs_dst.write((char *)&scaleX, sizeof(float));
    fs_dst.write((char *)&scaleY, sizeof(float));
    fs_dst.write((char *)&scaleZ, sizeof(float));
    fs_dst.write((char *)data,width*height*depth*sizeof(short));
    fs_dst.close();
}
```

But when I wrote integer values in file (width = 512 and height = 512), they are duplicated in binary file. To see this, I open original and my files in Hex-editor.

[image: Difference between binary files]

UPD: problem was because I wrote shorts as integers.

Comment: 'duplicated'?  You mean 'a copy was appended to the orignal?

Comment: What type are `width` and `height`?

Comment: Definitely, this is C++, rather than C...

Comment: I think @JohnnyMopp got it. Maybe the machine is 64 bit too.

Comment: How do you read the file in first place ?

Comment: @martin-james No, I try to show difference between 512 in original binary file and in my binary file. width and height are integers.

Comment: How do you read width?

Comment: Could you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with only the write part. BTW what is your platform ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I read and all variables read good     fread(&width,sizeof(int),1,stream);
       fread(&height,sizeof(int),1,stream);
        fread(&depth,sizeof(int),1,stream);

       fread(&scaleX,sizeof(float),1,stream);
       fread(&scaleY,sizeof(float),1,stream);
       fread(&scaleZ,sizeof(float),1,stream);

Comment: @VasilyevEugene please put that into your question. `fread(&width,sizeof(int),1,stream);` : you use `sizeof(int)` and when writing you use `sizeof(_int32)`. You understand what that could mean ?

Comment: Does it help if you replace `fread` with `fread(&width,sizeof(__int32),1,stream); ` and change type of `width` to `__int32`?

Comment: @MohitJain i should change writing code, because reading good.

Comment: Oh, I found error in my code! Width and height was shorts, and when I wrote their as integers, they duplicated in binary file. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of int, use __int32.